# Idiomatic Scala to iterate over all substrings

Tags: scala, functional-programming, idioms

Something less imperative than this:

`def subs(s: String) = for {start <- 0 to s.length; end <- i to s.length} yield s.substring(start, end)`

Comment: Given that this code works fine you may want to post this to codereview instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: I am always confused by all the various stackexchange sites - there's programmers, codereview, stackoverflow, codegolf and about half a dozen others and in my experience I get better response here than anywhere else.

Comment: I could be wrong, thats just what it seems like to me. Codereview seems to have much longer snippets of code, but it is certainly for seeing if your code is idiomatic. But I agree stackoverflow seems to be a catch-all. Programmers seems to be more centered on the not actual coding part of programming, ie working in a team, working on documentation etc. Codegolf is just trying to get the smallest amount of code. Then again you have been here much longer than me it looks like.

Comment: I don't know why you think that's imperative. There's no mutating state and you are using `yield` (rather than some kind of accumulator mutation within a non-`yield` `for` body. It also seems more transparent than @Rogach's suggestion.

Comment: start and end are mutating state you can argue. I agree the snippet I have above is more readable than @rogach's and I would always use my snipper than his but there are less imperative solutions in languages that let you do a cross product of 2 lists (e.g. in Haskell).

Comment: @wrick - it's not a cross product, as I see it. How would you do such thing in Haskell?

Comment: `def subs(s: String) = {val r = (0 to s.length)
  for {(start,end) <- r X r; if start>=end} yield s.substring(start,end)
}`

Whenever you find yourself writing a double-for-loop in `i,j`, it is almost always a cross product of 2 ranges or lists.

Comment: @wrick - Well, scala's for comprehension is a bit more verbose that haskell's.

Comment: What is that `i`? Do you mean `start`?

Comment: Yes. In general I meant any double loops.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
scala> "asdf".inits.flatMap(_.tails).toList
res2: List[String] = List(asdf, sdf, df, f, "", asd, sd, d, "", as, s, "", a, "", "")
```

If you want to remove empty strings:

```
scala> "asdf".inits.flatMap(_.tails.toList.init).toList
res3: List[String] = List(asdf, sdf, df, f, asd, sd, d, as, s, a)
```

But note that this incantation is not so obvious to the reader, as @Randall Schulz points out in comments. Your original version, on the other hand, is instantly clear.

Comment: +1, although IMO it'd be even better without the repeat empty string.

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo - it generates the same result as the snippet in the question. I'm actually can't think of a nice way to get rid of empty strings - I could append `.filter(_.nonEmpty)`, but that would be not so clean.

Comment: Yea, that's why I didn't suggest a solution myself, doesn't seem to be a way to avoid using `filter`. It would be even less clean if you wanted to keep a single empty string. `toSet` probably wouldn't work either, as I can imagine a use case where you want to iterate over repeats (with the exception of empty string).

Comment: Instead of `flatten` you could use `"asdf".inits.flatMap(_.tails).toList`

Comment: Removing the empty strings could also be done with `dropRight`, but that makes it a bit long: `"asdf".inits.toSeq.dropRight(1).flatMap(_.tails.toSeq dropRight 1).toList`

Comment: If you `filter` before `toList`, you will filter the iterator lazily, instead of creating a List and then traversing that.

Comment: @BenJames Actually, that's not true. If you use it as a `view` or use `withFilter` it will be done lazily, otherwise `filter` is not a lazy operation.

Comment: @Alex, for an `Iterator`, `filter` and `withFilter` are exactly the same, so they are equally lazy.

Comment: @BenJames Sure, but `flatten` returns a `Seq` no?

Comment: @Alex no, flattening a nested `Iterator` returns an `Iterator`. (In Scala 2.9+ at least.)

Comment: @BenJames Ah, right, I stand corrected. I skimmed over the fact that it was an `Iterator[Iterator[String]]`. (I also wasn't near a computer with Scala installed to test it out myself, apologies for the questions)

Comment: @Alex no problem. Anyway I think @EECOLOR's suggestion of `flatMap` is nicer than `map`/`flatten`.

Comment: In fact I'd suggest  `"asdf".inits.flatMap(_.tails).withFilter(!_.isEmpty).toList` to filter empty strings

Comment: What is the time complexity of this ? Is it n^3 ?

Comment: @Jessica - yes, it's O(n^3). You can optimize it by avoiding copying the strings (using something like CharBuffer), that will get complexity to O(n^2) and save lots of memory in the process. However, depending on your exact use case there is probably a way to improve time&memory usage even further by improving the algorithm.