# Functional way to find the Longest Common Substring between two strings in scala

Tags: scala

Here is a `imperative` solution:

```
def longestCommonSubstring(a: String, b: String) : String = {
    def loop(m: Map[(Int, Int), Int], bestIndices: List[Int], i: Int, j: Int) : String = {
      if (i > a.length) {
        b.substring(bestIndices(1) - m((bestIndices(0),bestIndices(1))), bestIndices(1))
      } else if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
        loop(m + ((i,j) -> 0), bestIndices, if(j == b.length) i + 1 else i, if(j == b.length) 0 else j + 1)
      } else if (a(i-1) == b(j-1) && math.max(m((bestIndices(0),bestIndices(1))), m((i-1,j-1)) + 1) == (m((i-1,j-1)) + 1)) {
        loop(
          m + ((i,j) -> (m((i-1,j-1)) + 1)),
          List(i, j),
          if(j == b.length) i + 1 else i,
          if(j == b.length) 0 else j + 1
        )
      } else {
        loop(m + ((i,j) -> 0), bestIndices, if(j == b.length) i + 1 else i, if(j == b.length) 0 else j + 1)
      }
    }
    loop(Map[(Int, Int), Int](), List(0, 0), 0, 0)
  }
```

I am looking for a more compact and `functional way` to find the  **Longest Common Substring**.

Comment: I don't follow the logic in this solution. Is there a high-level description of what is going on?

Comment: The high-level description I was seeking is "A character index and comparison technique which avoids creating lots of String instances."

Comment: The OP's code has several bugs in it. I have fixed them and put the results in the following visual diff (OP code is on the left, and my fixes are on the right): http://www.mergely.com/7oxoO0s3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def getAllSubstrings(str: String): Set[String] = {
  str.inits.flatMap(_.tails).toSet
}
def longestCommonSubstring(str1: String, str2: String): String = {
  val str1Substrings = getAllSubstrings(str1)
  val str2Substrings = getAllSubstrings(str2)

  str1Substrings.intersect(str2Substrings).maxBy(_.length)
}
```

First get all possible substrings (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862347/idiomatic-scala-to-iterate-over-all-substrings)) in a set (to remove duplicates) for both strings and then intersect those sets and find the longest of the common substrings.

Comment: This solution seems very CPU and GC inefficient for non-trivial sizes as it is a Cartesian Product. Imagining two `String`s, each with a length of 10,000 `Char`s, that's a huge number of permutations to pre-calculate of which many may be unused if the `length` of the answer ends up being more than 2,500 `Char`s. It is maximally inefficient for both CPU execution and GC memory. My solution is optimized exactly around avoiding these inefficiencies by using streaming via `LazyList` (or `Stream` if on a version of Scala prior to 2.13): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027618/501113

Answer (score 6):

The code you have is already functional and not that complex. It also  has asymptotically better time efficiency than the other currently posted solutions.

I'd just simplify it, clean up a bit and fix the bug:

```
def longestCommonSubstring(a: String, b: String) = {  
  def loop(bestLengths: Map[(Int, Int), Int], bestIndices: (Int, Int), i: Int, j: Int): String = {
    if (i > a.length) {
      val bestJ = bestIndices._2
      b.substring(bestJ - bestLengths(bestIndices), bestJ)
    } else {
      val currentLength = if (a(i-1) == b(j-1)) bestLengths(i-1, j-1) + 1 else 0
      loop(
        if (currentLength != 0) bestLengths + ((i, j) -> currentLength) else bestLengths, 
        if (currentLength > bestLengths(bestIndices)) (i, j) else bestIndices, 
        if (j == b.length) i + 1 else i,
        if (j == b.length) 1 else j + 1)
    }
  }

  if (b.isEmpty) ""
  else loop(Map.empty[(Int, Int), Int].withDefaultValue(0), (0, 0), 1, 1)
}
```

Comment: Just want to throw in, that he asked for a compact (which I understood as readable) solution. While your solution might have a better efficiency, debugging this code might prove harder for some people. Nonetheless it's of course important to be mentioned.

Comment: @thwiegan I actually agree with you. One reason I posted this answer is to address the misconception that the original code is not functional: there's no mutability in it, it's just a tail-recursive function.

Comment: @thwiegan Also I think that in general for algorithmic code, after you have already written the more efficient version and its unit tests, there is little need for future maintenance, except maybe adding new functionality. But the problem usually is spending time to write and test it initially, and whether it would actually run faster on your data sizes... So I think your point is correct, but I wanted to point out this alternative as well.

Comment: I don't follow the logic in this solution any more than my not following it in the OP's text. Is there a high-level description of what is going on?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium This is a simple loop in a tail recursive form. `bestLengths(i, j)` is the length of the common substring that ends at indexes `i` in `a` and `j` in `b`. Then in a loop for each `i`, for each `j` we add another letter to `bestLengths(i - 1, j - 1)`, if `a(i) == b(j)`.

Comment: @Kolmar Tysvm for your explanation. I needed it to be higher level than even that. I've now investigated the code. And the high-level answer I was seeking is "A character index and comparison technique which avoids creating lots of `String` instances." There are two problems with it which I will describe in the next two comments.

Comment: When called as such, `longestCommonSubstring("A", "")`, it throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium I've fixed the `longestCommonSubstring("A", "")` bug, thank you for noticing. This solution is quadratic `O(n*m)`, and yours is cubic `O(n^2*m)`, so for 2 large strings (of size 10000+) this one is considerably faster. It was slower before my last edit, but I have just added an optimization to avoid storing 0 values in the Map, so now it's very fast. Try measuring it yourself: on my machine for 2 strings of size 11000 and common string of size 1000 this solution runs in 11 seconds and yours runs in 320 seconds.

Comment: @Kolmar To improve efficiency and readability, you might consider changing `if (b.isEmpty) ""` to `if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) ""`.

Comment: @Kolmar I have now implemented a new solution that is over 3 times as fast as your solution. Check out `longestCommonSubstringsFast` in my second answer located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071041/501113

Comment: @Kolmar I just added a bonus solution which is almost 3 times faster than my prior fastest making it almost 9 times as fast as your solution. Checkout `longestCommonSubstringsUltimate` in my second answer located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071041/501113

Answer (score 5):

**Sidenote:** This is my third answer to this question because StackOverflow policy does not allow fundamentally replacing the content of a prior answer. And thanks to feedback from @Kolmar, this new answer is much more performant than [my prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027618/501113).

---

The LCS (Longest Common Substring) problem space has had many hours invested in which to find the optimal solution strategy. To observe the more general computer science problem and the optimal strategy, please review [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). Further down in this Wikipedia article is some [pseudocode describing an implementation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode).

Based on the Wikipedia article pseudocode, I will present several different solutions. The purpose is to allow one to copy/paste the specific solution which is needed without having to do much refactoring:

1. `LCSubstr`: Translation into Scala of [the Wikipedia article pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode) which uses an *imperative mutable style*
2. `LCSubstrFp`: Refactoring of `LCSubstr` into the idiomatic *Scala functional immutable style*
3. `longestCommonSubstrings`: Refactoring of `LCSubstrFp` to use descriptive names (such as `left` & `right` instead of `s` and `t`) and to skip storing zero lengths in the `Map`
4. `longestCommonSubstringsFast`: Refactoring of `longestCommonSubstrings` to deeply optimize for both CPU and memory
5. `longestCommonSubstringsWithIndexes`: Refactoring of `longestCommonSubstringsFast` to enhance the return value by expanding each entry into a tuple of `(String, (Int, Int))` which includes both the found substring and the index within each input `String` at which the substring was found (**CAUTION:** This creates a combinatorial expansion of the index pairs if the same `String` appears more than once)
6. `firstLongestCommonSubstring`: An efficiency-focused version of `longestCommonSubstringsFast` which provides an opportunity to terminate early when only caring about the first LCS and would like to ignore the others of the same size.
7. ***BONUS:*** `longestCommonSubstringsUltimate`: Refactoring of `longestCommonSubstringsFast` to add internal implementation mutability while externally retaining the function's referential transparency.

The more direct answer to the OP's request would fall be somewhere between `LCSubstrFp` and `longestCommonSubstringsFast`. `LCSubstrFp` is the most direct, but fairly inefficient. Using `longestCommonSubstringsFast` is substantially more efficient as it ends up using far less CPU and GC. And if internal mutuability contained and constrained within a function's implementation is acceptable, then `longestCommonSubstringsUltimate` is by far the version with the smallest CPU burden and memory footprint.

---

### LCSubstr

Translation into Scala of [the Wikipedia article pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode) which uses an *imperative mutable style*.

The intention is to come as close as it is possible with Scala to reproduce a one-to-one implementation. For example, Scala assumes zero-based indexing for String where the pseudocode clearly uses one-based indexing which required several tweaks.

```
def LCSubstr(s: String, t: String): scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] =
  if (s.nonEmpty && t.nonEmpty) {
    val l: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int), Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty
    var z: Int = 0
    var ret: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty

    (0 until s.length).foreach {
      i =>
        (0 until t.length).foreach {
          j =>
            if (s(i) == t(j)) {
              if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
                l += ((i, j) -> 1)
              else
                l += ((i, j) -> (l((i - 1, j - 1)) + 1))
              if (l((i, j)) > z) {
                z = l((i, j))
                ret = scala.collection.mutable.Set(s.substring(i - z + 1, i + 1))
              }
              else
                if (l((i, j)) == z)
                  ret += s.substring(i - z + 1, i + 1)
            } else
              l += ((i, j) -> 0)
        }
    }

    ret
  }
  else scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty
```

---

### LCSubstrFp

Refactoring of `LCSubstr` into the idiomatic *Scala functional immutable style*.

All imperative and mutation code have been replaced with function and immutable counterparts. The two `for` loops have been replaced with recursion.

```
def LCSubstrFp(s: String, t: String): Set[String] =
  if (s.nonEmpty && t.nonEmpty) {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(
      i: Int = 0,
      j: Int = 0,
      z: Int = 0,
      l: Map[(Int, Int), Int] = Map.empty,
      ret: Set[String] = Set.empty
    ): Set[String] =
      if (i < s.length) {
        val (newI, newJ) =
          if (j < t.length - 1) (i, j + 1)
          else (i + 1, 0)
        val lij =
          if (s(i) != t(j)) 0
          else
            if ((i == 0) || (j == 0)) 1
            else l((i - 1, j - 1)) + 1
        recursive(
          newI,
          newJ,
          if (lij > z) lij
          else z,
          l + ((i, j) -> lij),
          if (lij > z) Set(s.substring(i - lij + 1, i + 1))
          else
            if ((lij == z) && (z > 0)) ret + s.substring(i - lij + 1, i + 1)
            else ret
        )
      }
      else ret

    recursive()
  }
  else Set.empty
```

---

### longestCommonSubstrings

Refactoring of `LCSubstrFp` to use descriptive names (such as `left` & `right` instead of `s` and `t`) and to skip storing zero lengths in the `Map`.

Besides enhancing readability, this refactoring dispenses with storing zero-length values in `lengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter` substantially reducing the amount of "memory churn". Again in a tweak towards the functional style, the return value has also been enhanced to never return an empty `Set` by wrapping the `Set` in an `Option`. If the value returned is a `Some`, the contained `Set` will always contain at least one item.

```
def longestCommonSubstrings(left: String, right: String): Option[Set[String]] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (left.length < right.length) (left, right)
      else (right, left)

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(
      indexLonger: Int = 0,
      indexShorter: Int = 0,
      currentLongestLength: Int = 0,
      lengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter: Map[(Int, Int), Int] = Map.empty,
      accumulator: List[Int] = Nil
    ): (Int, List[Int]) =
      if (indexLonger < longer.length) {
        val length =
          if (longer(indexLonger) != shorter(indexShorter)) 0
          else
            if ((indexShorter == 0) || (indexLonger == 0)) 1
            else lengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter.getOrElse((indexLonger - 1, indexShorter - 1), 0) + 1
        val newCurrentLongestLength =
          if (length > currentLongestLength) length
          else currentLongestLength
        val newLengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter =
          if (length > 0) lengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter + ((indexLonger, indexShorter) -> length)
          else lengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter
        val newAccumulator =
          if ((length < currentLongestLength) || (length == 0)) accumulator
          else {
            val entry = indexShorter - length + 1
            if (length > currentLongestLength) List(entry)
            else entry :: accumulator
          }
        if (indexShorter < shorter.length - 1)
          recursive(
            indexLonger,
            indexShorter + 1,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            newLengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter,
            newAccumulator
          )
        else
          recursive(
            indexLonger + 1,
            0,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            newLengthByIndexLongerAndIndexShorter,
            newAccumulator
          )
      }
      else (currentLongestLength, accumulator)

    val (length, indexShorters) = recursive()
    if (indexShorters.nonEmpty)
      Some(
        indexShorters
          .map {
            indexShorter =>
              shorter.substring(indexShorter, indexShorter + length)
          }
          .toSet
      )
    else None
  }
  else None
```

---

### longestCommonSubstringsFast

Refactoring of `longestCommonSubstrings` to deeply optimize for both CPU and memory.

Eliminating every ounce of inefficiency while staying functional and immutable, execution speed is enhanced by several times over `longestCommonSubstrings`. The bulk of the cost reductions were achieved by replacing the `Map` of the entire matrix with a pair of `List`s tracking only the current and prior rows.

To easily see the differences from `longestCommonSubstrings`, [please view this visual diff](http://www.mergely.com/cEBxCINZ/).

```
def longestCommonSubstringsFast(left: String, right: String): Option[Set[String]] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (left.length < right.length) (left, right)
      else (right, left)

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(
      indexLonger: Int = 0,
      indexShorter: Int = 0,
      currentLongestLength: Int = 0,
      lengthsPrior: List[Int] = List.fill(shorter.length)(0),
      lengths: List[Int] = Nil,
      accumulator: List[Int] = Nil
    ): (Int, List[Int]) =
      if (indexLonger < longer.length) {
        val length =
          if (longer(indexLonger) != shorter(indexShorter)) 0
          else lengthsPrior.head + 1
        val newCurrentLongestLength =
          if (length > currentLongestLength) length
          else currentLongestLength
        val newAccumulator =
          if ((length < currentLongestLength) || (length == 0)) accumulator
          else {
            val entry = indexShorter - length + 1
            if (length > currentLongestLength) List(entry)
            else entry :: accumulator
          }
        if (indexShorter < shorter.length - 1)
          recursive(
            indexLonger,
            indexShorter + 1,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            lengthsPrior.tail,
            length :: lengths,
            newAccumulator
          )
        else
          recursive(
            indexLonger + 1,
            0,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            0 :: lengths.reverse,
            Nil,
            newAccumulator
          )
      }
      else (currentLongestLength, accumulator)

    val (length, indexShorters) = recursive()
    if (indexShorters.nonEmpty)
      Some(
        indexShorters
          .map {
            indexShorter =>
              shorter.substring(indexShorter, indexShorter + length)
          }
          .toSet
      )
    else None
  }
  else None
```

---

### longestCommonSubstringsWithIndexes

Refactoring of `longestCommonSubstringsFast` to enhance the return value by expanding each entry into a tuple of `(String, (Int, Int))` which includes both the found substring and the index within each input `String` at which the substring was found.

**CAUTION:** This creates a combinatorial expansion of the index pairs if the same `String` appears more than once.

Again in a tweak towards the functional style, the return value has also been enhanced to never return an empty `List` by wrapping the `List` in an `Option`. If the value returned is a `Some`, the contained `List` will always contain at least one item.

```
def longestCommonSubstringsWithIndexes(left: String, right: String): Option[List[(String, (Int, Int))]] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    val isLeftShorter = left.length < right.length
    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (isLeftShorter) (left, right)
      else (right, left)

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(
      indexLonger: Int = 0,
      indexShorter: Int = 0,
      currentLongestLength: Int = 0,
      lengthsPrior: List[Int] = List.fill(shorter.length)(0),
      lengths: List[Int] = Nil,
      accumulator: List[(Int, Int)] = Nil
    ): (Int, List[(Int, Int)]) =
      if (indexLonger < longer.length) {
        val length =
          if (longer(indexLonger) != shorter(indexShorter)) 0
          else lengthsPrior.head + 1
        val newCurrentLongestLength =
          if (length > currentLongestLength) length
          else currentLongestLength
        val newAccumulator =
          if ((length < currentLongestLength) || (length == 0)) accumulator
          else {
            val entry = (indexLonger - length + 1, indexShorter - length + 1)
            if (length > currentLongestLength) List(entry)
            else entry :: accumulator
          }
        if (indexShorter < shorter.length - 1)
          recursive(
            indexLonger,
            indexShorter + 1,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            lengthsPrior.tail,
            length :: lengths,
            newAccumulator
          )
        else
          recursive(
            indexLonger + 1,
            0,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            0 :: lengths.reverse,
            Nil,
            newAccumulator
          )
      }
      else (currentLongestLength, accumulator)

    val (length, indexPairs) = recursive()
    if (indexPairs.nonEmpty)
      Some(
        indexPairs
          .reverse
          .map {
            indexPair =>
              (
                longer.substring(indexPair._1, indexPair._1 + length),
                if (isLeftShorter) indexPair.swap else indexPair
              )
          }
      )
    else None
  }
  else None
```

---

### firstLongestCommonSubstring

An efficiency-focused version of `longestCommonSubstringsFast` which provides an opportunity to terminate early when only caring about the first LCS and would like to ignore the others of the same size.

```
def firstLongestCommonSubstring(left: String, right: String): Option[(String, (Int, Int))] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    val isLeftShorter = left.length < right.length
    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (isLeftShorter) (left, right)
      else (right, left)

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(
      indexLonger: Int = 0,
      indexShorter: Int = 0,
      currentLongestLength: Int = 0,
      lengthsPrior: List[Int] = List.fill(shorter.length)(0),
      lengths: List[Int] = Nil,
      accumulator: Option[(Int, Int)] = None
    ): Option[(Int, (Int, Int))] =
      if (indexLonger < longer.length) {
        val length =
          if (longer(indexLonger) != shorter(indexShorter)) 0
          else lengthsPrior.head + 1
        val newAccumulator =
          if (length > currentLongestLength) Some((indexLonger - length + 1, indexShorter - length + 1))
          else accumulator
        if (length < shorter.length) {
          val newCurrentLongestLength =
            if (length > currentLongestLength) length
            else currentLongestLength
          if (indexShorter < shorter.length - 1)
            recursive(
              indexLonger,
              indexShorter + 1,
              newCurrentLongestLength,
              lengthsPrior.tail,
              length :: lengths,
              newAccumulator
            )
          else
            recursive(
              indexLonger + 1,
              0,
              newCurrentLongestLength,
              0 :: lengths.reverse,
              Nil,
              newAccumulator
            )
        }
        else
          recursive(longer.length, 0, length, lengthsPrior, lengths, newAccumulator) //early terminate
      }
      else accumulator.map((currentLongestLength, _))

    recursive().map {
      case (length, indexPair) =>
        (
          longer.substring(indexPair._1, indexPair._1 + length),
          if (isLeftShorter) indexPair.swap else indexPair
        )
    }
  }
  else None
```

---

***BONUS:***

### longestCommonSubstringsUltimate

Refactoring of `longestCommonSubstringsFast` to add internal implementation mutability while externally retaining the function's referential transparency.

Further eliminating every ounce of inefficiency while staying functional and referentially transparent (engaging in utilizing mutability within the implementation itself which some consider is *not* validly functional), execution speed is enhanced by almost three times over `longestCommonSubstringsFast`. The bulk of the cost reductions were by replacing the pair of `List`s with a single `Array`.

To easily see the differences from `longestCommonSubstringsFast`, [please view this visual diff](http://www.mergely.com/lBrX5F6b/).

```
def longestCommonSubstringsUltimate(left: String, right: String): Option[Set[String]] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (left.length < right.length) (left, right)
      else (right, left)
    val lengths: Array[Int] = new Array(shorter.length) //mutable

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(
      indexLonger: Int = 0,
      indexShorter: Int = 0,
      currentLongestLength: Int = 0,
      lastIterationLength: Int = 0,
      accumulator: List[Int] = Nil
    ): (Int, List[Int]) =
      if (indexLonger < longer.length) {
        val length =
          if (longer(indexLonger) != shorter(indexShorter)) 0
          else
            if (indexShorter == 0) 1
            else lastIterationLength + 1
        val newLastIterationLength = lengths(indexShorter)
        lengths(indexShorter) = length //mutation
        val newCurrentLongestLength =
          if (length > currentLongestLength) length
          else currentLongestLength
        val newAccumulator =
          if ((length < currentLongestLength) || (length == 0)) accumulator
          else {
            val entry = indexShorter - length + 1
            if (length > currentLongestLength) List(entry)
            else entry :: accumulator
          }
        if (indexShorter < shorter.length - 1)
          recursive(
            indexLonger,
            indexShorter + 1,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            newLastIterationLength,
            newAccumulator
          )
        else
          recursive(
            indexLonger + 1,
            0,
            newCurrentLongestLength,
            newLastIterationLength,
            newAccumulator
          )
      }
      else (currentLongestLength, accumulator)

    val (length, indexShorters) = recursive()
    if (indexShorters.nonEmpty)
      Some(
        indexShorters
          .map {
            indexShorter =>
              shorter.substring(indexShorter, indexShorter + length)
          }
          .toSet
      )
    else None
  }
  else None
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** DO NOT USE THE APPROACH DETAILED BELOW.

I should have paid more attention to the OP's expressly provided implementation. Unfortunately, I got distracted by all the other answers using inefficient `String` oriented comparisons and went on a tear to provide my own optimized version of those gleeful that I was able to use `Stream` and `LazyList`.

I've now added an [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071041/501113) (per StackOverflow's policy) which covers substantially faster Scala functional style solutions.

---

A `Stream` focused solution might be the following:

```
def substrings(a:String, len:Int): Stream[String] =
  if(len==0) 
    Stream.empty
  else 
    a.tails.toStream.takeWhile(_.size>=len).map(_.take(len)) #::: substrings(a, len-1)

def longestCommonSubstring(a:String, b:String) = 
  substrings(a, a.length).dropWhile(sub => !b.contains(sub)).headOption
```

Here *substrings* method returns Stream producing decreasing length substrings of the original string, for example "test" produces "test", "tes", "est", "te", "es",...

Method *longestCommonSubstring* takes first substring generated from *a* which is contained in string *b*

Comment: Am I missing something? #:: gives me type mismatch (expected String, actual Stream[String]). ++ works fine for me

Comment: Instead of dropWhile and headOption, you can do `substrings(a, a.length).find(b.contains)`

Comment: @thweigan I just edited to fix both errors in the code (changed `#::` to `#:::`, and changed `b.contanis(sub)` to `b.contains(sub)`).

Comment: In addition to the comment @thwiegan left regarding replacing "`dropWhile` and `headOption`", the `longestCommonSubstring` function can be made more efficient if it were to ensure substrings was called on the shorter of the two `String` parameters as I've done in my solution inspired in part by this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027618/501113

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** After posting this answer, and thanks to @Kolmar's feedback, I discovered that a `Char` indexing strategy was substantially faster (like at least an order of magnitude). I've now added an [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071041/501113) (per StackOverflow's policy) which covers substantially faster Scala functional style solutions.

I should have paid more attention to the OP's specifically provided implementation. Unfortunately, I got distracted by all the other answers using inefficient `String` oriented comparisons and went on a tear to provide my own optimized version of those gleeful that I was able to use `Stream` and `LazyList`.

---

Beyond the OP's request, I had several additional requirements for composing a solution to finding the longest common substring (LCS) between two String instances.

---

### **Solution Requirements:**

1. Eagerly find the *first* LCS between two `String` instances
2. Minimize CPU effort by comparing fewer `String` instances
3. Minimize GC effort by producing fewer `String` instances
4. Maximize being Scala idiomatic, including use of the Scala Collections API

---

The first goal is to capture the general search strategy. The process starts with the `left` `String` instance, producing an ordered list of substrings from the longest (the original `String` instance itself) to the shortest (single characters). For example, if the `left` `String` instance contains "ABCDEF", the resulting list of `String` instances should be produced and in exactly this order:

```
[
  ABCDEF,
  ABCDE, BCDEF,
  ABCD, BCDE, CDEF,
  ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF,
  AB,BC,CD,DE,EF,
  A,B,C,D,E,F
]
```

Next, an iteration is started through this list of `left` substring instances, halting as soon as a particular `left` substring instance is found at any index within the `right` `String` instance. When a `left` substring instance is found, it is returned. Otherwise, an indication there were no matches found is returned.

There are two specific things to note about the "eager" approach to satisfying Solution Requirement #1:

- The `left` substring instance found could appear at more than one index in the `right` `String` instance. This means searching for the `left` substring instance from the start of the `right` `String` instance using `indexOf` could result in a different index value than searching from the end of the `right` `String` instance using `lastIndexOf`.
- There could be a second (different) `left` substring instance of the same length which also appears in the `right` `String` instance. This implementation ignores that possibility.

---

### **Solution for Scala 2.13/Dotty (a.k.a 3.0) - uses [LazyList](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.2/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html):**

`Stream` was deprecated as of 2.13.

```
def longestCommonSubstring(left: String, right: String): Option[String] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    def substrings(string: String): LazyList[String] = {
      def recursive(size: Int = string.length): LazyList[String] = {
        if (size > 0) {
          def ofSameLength: LazyList[String] =
            (0 to (string.length - size))
              .iterator.to(LazyList)
              .map(offset => string.substring(offset, offset + size))

          ofSameLength #::: recursive(size - 1)
        }
        else
          LazyList.empty
      }

      recursive()
    }

    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (left.length <= right.length)
        (left, right)
      else
        (right, left)
    substrings(shorter).find(longer.contains)
  }
  else
    None
```

---

### **Solution Scala 2.12 and prior - uses [Stream](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.11/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html):**

```
def longestCommonSubstring(left: String, right: String): Option[String] =
  if (left.nonEmpty && right.nonEmpty) {
    def substrings(string: String): Stream[String] = {
      def recursive(size: Int = string.length): Stream[String] = {
        if (size > 0) {
          def ofSameLength: Stream[String] =
            (0 to (string.length - size))
              .toStream
              .map(offset => string.substring(offset, offset + size))

          ofSameLength #::: recursive(size - 1)
        }
        else
          Stream.empty
      }

      recursive()
    }

    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (left.length <= right.length)
        (left, right)
      else
        (right, left)
    substrings(shorter).find(longer.contains)
  }
  else
    None
```

---

### **Notes:**

- Providing a [visual diff between the two versions](http://www.mergely.com/NKpeUkBF/) to quickly see the delta
- To cover the various edge cases (ex: providing an empty `String` as input), an `Option[String]` is used for the function's return type.
- In satisfying Solution Requirements #2 and #3, the shorter of the two `String` instances is set as `shorter` to reduce instantiations and comparisons with `String`s longer than the `longer` `String` instance.
- In satisfying Solution Requirements #2 and #3, the production of `shorter` substring instances are sub-batched by identical size with duplicates removed (via `distinct`). And then each sub-batch is added to a `LazyList` (or `Stream`). This ensures only the instantiation the `shorter` substring instances actually needed are provided to the `longer.contains` function.

Comment: Always using `distinct` is inefficient here. It takes a lot of time to do it for large strings, but the chance of having equal large substrings is very small. In my measurements for large strings the version with `distinct` is more than twice slower than the one with `.distinct` removed.

Comment: @Kolmar Tysvm for your comments and feedback. I just added an "Update" to this answer indicating I had created another answer where I flesh out the character indexing answer much more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a code with a *for* comprehension looks very clear and functional.

```
def getSubstrings(s:String) =
  for {
    start <- 0 until s.size
    end <- start to s.size

  } yield s.substring(start, end)

def getLongest(one: String, two: String): Seq[String] =

  getSubstrings(one).intersect(getSubstrings(two))
 .groupBy(_.length).maxBy(_._1)._2
```

The final function returns a Seq[String] as far as the result might contain several substrings with the same maximum length

Comment: This solution seems very CPU and GC inefficient for non-trivial sizes. Imagining two Strings, each with a length of 10,000 Chars, that's a huge number of permutations to pre-calculate of which many may be unused if the 'length' of the answer ends up being more than 2,500 Chars.

Comment: @a-kremlianski Your solution throws an exception if either String is empty. Here's what I did to fix the code as a diff (your code on the left and my fixed version on the right): http://www.mergely.com/ZgV14TLu/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solution to find the largest common Substring in Scala. This scans the source String for every character and find the substring associated with that character in target string.

```
object largestCommonStringFinder extends App {

  val comparisonResult = comparer("abd","bcarfbcmcgcdbdcd")

  def comparer(first:String, second:String):String = {
    val (firstVal, secondVal) = first.size > second.size match{
      case true  => (second, first)
      case false => (first, second)
    }

    val res1: Seq[List[(String, Int)]] = firstVal.zipWithIndex.map(startChar => {
      secondVal.map(String.valueOf(_)).zipWithIndex.filter( _._1 == String.valueOf(startChar._1)).toList
    })


    val res3: Seq[(List[(String, Int)], Int)] = res1.zipWithIndex.map((x: (List[(String, Int)], Int)) => {
      println(s"firstVal.isDefinedAt{${x._2 + 1}} => ${firstVal.isDefinedAt(x._2 + 1)}")
      println()
      firstVal.isDefinedAt(x._2 + 1) match {
        case true  => val res2 = x._1.map((y: (String, Int)) => {

                                    (0  to  (firstVal.size - (x._2 + 2))).map(_+ x._2).foldLeft(y)((intern, item) => finder(intern, firstVal, secondVal, item))

                                  })
                                (res2, x._2 + 1)
        case false => x
      }
    })

    res3.map(x => x._1).flatten.map(x => x._1).sortBy(x => (x.length, x.head)).reverse.head
  }

  def finder(y:(String, Int), firstVal:String, secondVal:String, sourceIndex:Int):(String, Int)={
    secondVal.isDefinedAt(y._2 + 1) match {
      case true => secondVal.charAt(y._2 + 1) == firstVal.charAt(sourceIndex + 1) match {
        case true => (y._1.concat(String.valueOf(secondVal.charAt(y._2 + 1))), y._2 + 1)
        case false => (y._1, y._2)
      }
      case false => y
    }
  }

}
```

This another approach will focus on finding the possible combination of substrings from the source string and findings these substrings in target string. out of all the substring found successfully in target, find the largest length string among all.

```
object largestCommonStringFinderNewApproach extends App {


  val comparisonResult = comparer("abcde","bcdearfbcmcgcdbadcd")

  println(comparisonResult)


    def comparer(first: String, second: String): String = {
      val (firstVal, secondVal) = first.size > second.size match {
        case true => (second, first)
        case false => (first, second)
      }

      findAllPossibleStrings(firstVal)
        .map(x => {
            secondVal.contains(x) match {
              case true  => (x, true)
              case false => (x, false)
            }
          })
        .filter(x => x._2 == true)
        .map(_._1)
        .sortBy(x => (x.length, x.head))
        .reverse
        .head
    }

    def findAllPossibleStrings(source:String):List[String]={
      (1 to source.size).reverse.map(x => {
        (0 to (source.size - x)).map(y => source.substring(y, x + y))
      }).flatMap(x => x).toList
    }

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this approach:

1. Get all substrings:

> left.inits.flatMap(_.tails)

2. Sort it in reverse order based on lenght

> .toList.sortBy(_.length).reverse

3. find the first match

> .find(right.contains(_)).get

Full function:

```
  def lcs(left: String, right: String) = {
    left.inits.flatMap(_.tails)
      .toList.sortBy(_.length).reverse
      .find(right.contains(_)).get
  }
```

Note:
get will never be empty, since initial string permutation also contains empty string, which will always match something.

Comment: This solution seems very CPU and GC inefficient for non-trivial sizes. Imagining two `String`s, each with a length of 10,000 `Char`s, that's a huge number of permutations to pre-calculate of which many may be unused if the 'length' of the answer ends up being more than 2,500 `Char`s.